# OpenCL through pure java

Tags: java, opencl, rootbeer

I'm interesting in the current state of GPGPU through OpenCL with pure java. I found two project [aparapi](https://code.google.com/p/aparapi/) and [Rootbeer](https://github.com/pcpratts/rootbeer1), but can't found any information about its actual state and perspectives. Other projects such as JavaCL and JOCL, needs C programming. What framework or library are mainstream for GPGPU through OpenCL, which provide pure java API for this purpose?

Comment: Do you mean to write your OpenCL on the host , i.e. writing kernel programs with a somehow fluent Java-API (like Java 8 Streams) without a logical break between host and device. OR would you like to write the device kernel code completely in Java, but having a split architecture model?

Comment: I would like to consider both variants. I've no architecture limitations. And all I want is stay on pure java as long as possible.

Comment: I've edited the question and removed my own opinion and question, implying opinion based answers. Please reopen the question.